# How do I configure the /etc/network/interfaces file?

Tags: networking

I tried to access a wireless device on my kubuntu system and I have no  access network to the network. I gave up on wireless and went back to my wired connection.

How do I add a device to /etc/network/interfaces so that /etc/init.d/networking start will restart my network interfaces?

Many thanks,

Steve

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish.  As it stands, I'm not sure why you'd want to attempt this.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to edit that file. Just use NetworkManager, in Kubuntu (KDE) you can access it from the drop-down menu next to the clock.